# Passing default argument after initialization

Tags: python

I have a python file with many functions.
Every function gets a `client` as the default argument,
but on the stage of function initialization, it does not exist yet.
He will be created in a `main` function inside `with` context manager.

How I can solve it (make `client` available in every function) and preserve a context manager as suggested in docs?

I tried to use `global` statement, `generator`, global variables, and `functools.partial` but all these attempts failed mostly because of a closed connection outside of the context manager.

```
...  # Many functions

def get_statistic_with(client: TelegramClient = client1):  # client1 is undefunded on this stage
    client.send_message(entity=config.BOT_NAME, message='/get_statistic_with')


def main():
    with TelegramClient('test_client`', config.API_ID, config.API_HASH) as client1, \
            TelegramClient('test_client1', config.API_ID, config.API_HASH) as client2:
    ...
```

I know that I can use a `class` to fix it but don't plan to create many instances, I only need to import and run the `main` function from another file.
I also can place all the functions inside `with` code block but it will be too ugly.
Passing a connection to every function is a pretty inconvenient.

Comment: How inconvenient would it be if the parameter did not have a default argument?

Answer (score 1):

You mentioned trying both global variables and `functools.partial` (which works a lot like a lambda function), and neither worked.

I believe the same methods you tried would work if you used **both** of those together.

Here is an example where I've done that (I used `lambda` but if you prefer `partial` it should be an easy substitution):

```
class TelegramClient:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def showProofOfWorking(self):
        print("--- SUCCESS! This is a TelegramClient named " + self.name)


# In order to avoid namespace errors, there must be a reference to the clients in global scope.
# However, the value of client1 doesn't need to be set until 'main', as will be demonstrated in the
# first of the three methods tested in this example code.
globalVars = {'client1': None, 'client2': None}
# For comparison purposes.  Compare how this globally scoped client reference acts relative to the function-scoped 'localClient' inside 'main'
otherGlobalClient = TelegramClient("OTHER CLIENT IN GLOBAL SCOPE")


def refersToGlobalClient(client = globalVars['client1']):
    client.showProofOfWorking()
    
def refersToGlobalWrappedClient(clientWrapper = lambda: globalVars['client1']):
    unwrappedClient = clientWrapper()
    unwrappedClient.showProofOfWorking()

def refersToLocalWrappedClient(clientWrapper = lambda: client1):
    unwrappedClient = clientWrapper()
    unwrappedClient.showProofOfWorking()


def main():
    client1 = TelegramClient('CLIENT 1')
    client2 = TelegramClient('CLIENT 2')
    # No references to this from the global scope:  it only exists inside 'main'
    otherLocalClient = TelegramClient('CLIENT ONLY IN LOCAL SCOPE')

    # Only 'client1' will be put into global scope.  'client2' is not defined outside the scope of 'main'.
    globalVars['client1'] = client1

    # -----  This is the only one of the three different methods tried here that works.  -----
    # It combines a global variable with a lambda function, which changes the reference of the wrapped global variable from a compile-time value to a runtime value,
    # circumventing the fact that at compile time, the value of the global variable will be None as it will not be set to its final value until inside 'main'.
    print("FIRST METHOD:  Global Scope plus Lambda Wrapper:  Works in All Cases")
    print("Inside main(), we will now call 'refersToGlobalWrappedClient' with its default argument, which is a function that returns the current value of 'globalVars['client1']'")
    refersToGlobalWrappedClient()
    print("\nNow we'll call the same function with a different argument from global scope.")
    refersToGlobalWrappedClient(lambda: otherGlobalClient)
    print("\nNow we'll call the same function with a different argument from local scope.")
    refersToGlobalWrappedClient(lambda: otherLocalClient)
    print("\n__________________________\n")

    print("SECOND METHOD:  Global Scope with No Wrapper:  Works With Arguments, Does Not Work With Default Parameter")
    print("Inside main(), we will now attempt to call 'refersToGlobalClient' with its default argument, which is 'globalVars['client1']'")
    try:
        refersToGlobalClient()
    except Exception as error:
        print("\nAN EXCEPTION OCCURRED!  Exception:")
        print(error)
    print("\nNow we'll call the same function with a different argument from global scope.")
    refersToGlobalClient(otherGlobalClient)
    print("\nNow we'll call the same function with a different argument from local scope.")
    refersToGlobalClient(otherLocalClient)
    print("\n__________________________\n")

    print("THIRD METHOD:  Local Scope with Lambda Wrapper:  ")
    print("Inside main(), we will now attempt to call 'refersToLocalClient' with its default argument, which is a function that returns 'client1'")
    try:
        refersToLocalWrappedClient()
    except Exception as error:
        print("\nAN EXCEPTION OCCURRED!  Exception:")
        print(error)
    print("\nNow we'll call the same function with a different argument from global scope.")
    refersToLocalWrappedClient(lambda: otherGlobalClient)
    print("\nNow we'll call the same function with a different argument from local scope.")
    refersToLocalWrappedClient(lambda: otherLocalClient)
    print("\n__________________________\n")


main()
```

Here, I tried three different methods.  Like you said, *only* adding a reference to `client1` in global scope, or *only* wrapping the reference to the not-yet-defined `client1` inside a function, do not work and cause errors when you try to use `client1` as a default argument.

But, if you *both* set up a reference to your `client1` in global scope (here, it's inside a `dict` called `globalVars`) *and* wrap the default `client1` parameter inside a function, you can call your functions successfully from inside `main()` with the default parameter (`client1`) or with any other `TelegramClient` as an argument.

The global scoped reference is necessary to avoid the namespace error `name 'client1' is not defined`.
The `lambda` wrapper is necessary to avoid the error you would get from the **value** of the global reference not being set until `main()` runs (at compile-time when the default parameters are evaluated, it will be `None` and you'd get the error `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'showProofOfWorking'`).

Answer (score 1):

Functions are objects and can have attributes. I don't see this feature used much here on SO and have seen criticisms of their use - if I recall it obfuscates and interferes with introspection, but sometimes my memory is faulty.

If you want to be able to call a function without passing an argument but the value of the argument is not *defined/calculated* till after the function's definition you could make use of a function attribute like this.

```
def f():
    return 3 * f.x

def main():
    f.x = 6

main()
print(f())
```

You will have to decide whether this is more advantageous than just defining the function with parameter's - without default arguments - and just passing the argument when the function is called. At least for me there is not enough information in your question and [mre] to really understand whether this approach will satisfy your need.

Maybe you should have a module level variable, before the function definition

```
client1 = None
..
def get_statistic_with(client: TelegramClient = client1):
    ...
```

then reassign in the with statement.

Comment: caveat: In the second solution, using `None`  will mess up the (static) type checking.